# VirtualBox VMs in the same network, not in the same as host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have operating systems running on my host machine in VirtualBox. I want these to be able to access the internet and see each other. I don't wan't to use the bridge option because I want them to be in a different network than the host. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a new network type in VirtualBox 4.3 called NAT Network what is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You should endow each VM with two network adapters. The first one will be of type NAT, allowing each VM to connect to the Internet. The second should be of type Internal network, which allows VMs to talk to each other but not to the host.

You find the [manual here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I found that there's a built in network type that does the same. Also, I couldn't get this working.